# Is karma action based or intention based?

Tags: karma

Karma is a universal. So is karma intention based or action based. Example : if I pushed someone because I wanted to hurt him but it endup saving his life.

**Will I get good karma for saying his life or will I get bad karma because I wanted to hurt him. My intention was wrong, but my actions was correct**.

Comment: I imagine karma is intention. When you mistakenly saved his life, you got angry. So you burned in the hell of anger & hate twice, when pushing and then when failing in your intention to hurt him.

Comment: Without any disrespect to anybody the answer you selected is nothing but a comment. You shouldn't be accepting such answers if you are seeking authentic info about Hinduism. This site is known for high quality answers mostly based on scriptures.

Comment: I believe you are confusing dharma with karma.. its some maa..its maa based :-) enjoy

Comment: It could be nice if you had a little chat with Naruto in the chatroom. He’ll explain which answers to accept and which not. I think since you’re relatively newer it maybe a little confusing eh? They insist on citing proper authentic sources and gurus for the answers not a plain 2 liner. See @Rickross ‘ answers for example. He is correct about accepting answers.